# How to refer to lines/rows in a "enumerated" table?

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate, tabularray, rows

The table is nothing more than unknown vocabulary for a book.

The first column gives the pagenumber of the book, apart from the titlepage alway as doublepage (2--3, 4--5, 6--7...), the second column is the Latin word, the third the translation. The pagenumber(s) of the doublepage are written only once, so the hold till the next pagebreak.

Now, I don't want to write the translation twice, if the unknown word appears again, but only refer to the doublepage (first column) where it first appeared: `4--5 & word1 \?label{word1} & translation1 \\ ... \\ 18--19 & word1 & see on \?ref{word1} \\`

I guess I also need a new format for the first column.

```
% uses-*- MODE: latex; TeX-engine: luatex; coding: utf-8; -*-
\RequirePackage{xpatch}
\RequirePackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\documentclass[paper=A6,fontsize=8pt,verbose,latin]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[main=latin,ngerman,greek.ancient]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e, luamaths, letltxmacro}
\defaultfontfeatures+{Ligatures={TeX,Common}}
% \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily,\sffamily]{Scale=MatchUppercase}
\setmainfont[Extension = .otf,%
             ItalicFont=NewCM10-BookItalic,%
             BoldFont=NewCM10-Bold,%
             BoldItalicFont=NewCM10-BoldItalic,%
             ]{NewCM10-Book}
\setsansfont{NewCMSans10-Book}             
\setmonofont{New Computer Modern10}
\usepackage{hyperref, zref-clever, zref-vario}
\zcsetup{hyperref=true,nameinlink,lang=latin}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{zref,booktabs,varwidth}
% \usepackage{uninormalize}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

% \title{Cattus Petasatus}
% \maketitle

\NewTblrTheme{cattus}{%
  \SetTblrStyle{firsthead}{font=\bfseries}
  \DefTblrTemplate{contfoot}{cattus}{}
  \SetTblrTemplate{contfoot}{cattus}
  \DefTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{cattus}{}
  \SetTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{cattus}
  \DefTblrTemplate{caption-tag}{cattus}{}
  \SetTblrTemplate{caption-tag}{cattus}
  \DefTblrTemplate{caption-sep}{cattus}{}
  \SetTblrTemplate{caption-sep}{cattus}
}

\begin{longtblr}[theme = cattus]{%
  colspec={Q[r]QX[l]}, row{1} =
    {font=\bfseries}, rowhead = 1, % headsep = 65pt, 
    column{1-2} = {font=\bfseries} , 
  }
  pagina & verba & versio \\\midrule
  0 & petasatus & de Graeco {\selectlanguage{greek}πεταννύναι},
    ">mit breiter Krempe"< \\\hline[dotted]
  1 & totum diem & Akk.\ d.\ zeitlichen Ausdehnung \\
  & {urceatim Adv.\\
    \textless urceus, -i} & {\\Kanne, Krug}
  \\\hline[dotted] % <--- \?label{urceatim} 
  2--3 & deses & untätig\\ % <--- \?label{deses}
  & fore & futurum esse \\
  & frigus, -oris & Kälte \\
  & foras  & nach draußen \\
  & lascivire & tamquam sine ullis vinculis ludere
  et persultare \\ % <--- \?label{lascivire}
  & quiescere & quies, -etis \\
  & quiescendi & Gen.\ d.\ Gerunds \\
  & stomachosus & verärgert \\\hline[dotted]
  4--5 & tremebundus & zitternd \\
  & pavor & timor \\\hline[dotted]
  6--7 & calcare & treten auf \\
  & huc & hierher \\\hline[dotted]
  8--9 & stropha & Trick \\
  & indicare & demonstrare \\
  & lascivire &  vide ad ? \\ % <--- \?ref{lascivire}
  & diem degere & den Tag verbringen\\\hline[dotted]
  10--11 & repente & plötzlich \\
  & discedere & weggehen \\
  & cavere & aufpassen auf \\\hline[dotted]
  12--13 & duce catto & abl.~abs. \\
  & nocivus & schädlich \\
  & ascendere & aufsteigen \\
  & sursum Adv. & aufwärts \\
  & surgere & sich erheben \\
  & descendere & absteigen \\
  & pavescere & timere \\
  & tremescere & zittern \\\hline[dotted]
  14--15 & per-cautus & sehr vorsichtig \\
  & mitis & nett \\
  & urceatim & vide ad ? \\ % <--- \?ref{urceatim}
  & sublimis & in der Höhe \\
  & librare & hochhalten \\ % <--- \?label{librare}
  & vibrare &  durchschütteln \\
  & galerus & Hut & \\\hline[dotted]
  16--17 & in promptu & in Reserve \\
  & careo alqua.\ re & mir fehlt etw. \\
  & comptus & Haarschmuck \\
  & gestare & tragen \\
  & collocare & plazieren \\
  & lanx  & Tablett\\
  & lascivire & vide ad ? \\ % <---\?ref{lascivire}
  & bellus & schön \\
  & libellum & liber parvus \\
  & librare & vide ad ? \\ % <--- \?ref{librare}
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\makeatletter
\def\mylabel#1{\@bsphack
  \protected@write\@auxout{}%
         {\string\newlabel{#1}{{\mypage}{}}}%
  \@esphack}

\newcommand{\setlabel}[1]{%
  #1\def\@tempa{#1}\ifx\@tempa\@empty\else\message{pagina#1}\gdef\mypage{#1}\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{longtblr}[theme = cattus]{%
  colspec={Q[r]QX[l]}, row{1} =
    {font=\bfseries}, rowhead = 1, % headsep = 65pt, 
    column{1-2} = {font=\bfseries} , 
    cell{2-Z}{1} = {cmd=\setlabel}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  }
```

```
  & lascivire & tamquam sine ullis vinculis ludere
  et persultare \mylabel{lascivire} \\% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

```
  & lascivire &  vide ad  \ref{lascivire} \\% <<<<<<<<<<
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to add a hyperlink to the referred entry? In several document viewers kind of pop up of the links appear, which is quite convenient on the screen as you don't have to search the linked entry. I tried \zref, \vref, vzref... none of which works.